# How to pass fractional value in buyPrice?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, tokens

I am deploying an erc-20 token with 18 decimal places. And I want that if someone calls the buy function with 1 ETH, the contract should return 1500 tokens to `msg.sender`. The `buy` function is implemented as:

```
function buy() public payable returns (uint){
       require(msg.sender != address(0));
       require(msg.value >= 0);
       uint amount = msg.value.div(buyPrice);
       require(balances[this] >= amount);
       uint oldBalance = balances[this].add(balances[msg.sender]);
       balances[this] = balances[this].sub(amount);
       balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(amount);
       uint newBalance = balances[this].add(balances[msg.sender]);
       assert(newBalance == oldBalance);
       Transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);
       return amount;   
  }
```

As per the implementation of this method, the `buyPrice` should be `1/1500`. But since buyPrice is uint, I can not pass decimal values to this variable.

Is there any workaround? Do I need to change the standard buy function to suit my case?

Answer (score 1):

When you say the `buyPrice` should be 1/1500, do you mean for every 1 eth the user should receive 1500 of the token? If that is the case then then the `buyPrice` should actually be 1500, and renamed to something like `tokensToEth`, and the amount assignment should be `uint amount = msg.value.mul(tokensToEth);`

Answer (score 0):

Posting solution to m own question. As I thought I had to make changes in the standard buy function.

**Change 1:** The amount was multiplied by 1 ether i.e. 10^18, so the buy price in my case became 10^18/1500. Now buyPrice is being set in Wei.

**Chnage2:** First multiply `msg.value` with `1 ether` and then divide by `buyPrice`. Don't reverse the order as dividing very small value first may result in zero value and then multiply will have no effect.

**Change 3:** Check if amount is greater than zero before proceeding by using `require(amount > 0);`

Final buy function became:

```
function buy() public payable returns (uint){
       require(msg.sender != address(0));
       require(msg.value >= 0);
       uint amount = msg.value.mul(1 ether).div(buyPrice);
       require(amount > 0);
       require(balances[this] >= amount);
       uint oldBalance = balances[this].add(balances[msg.sender]);
       balances[this] = balances[this].sub(amount);
       balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(amount);
       uint newBalance = balances[this].add(balances[msg.sender]);
       assert(newBalance == oldBalance);
       Transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);
       return amount;    
  }
```